# Android App in-place update

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have an application which is deployed to some pretty remote, data connection starved regions of the world, specifically to health workers.

These people have minimal data connections and the app requires regular updates to provide increased functionality and critical bugfixes.

The problem we have is that the APK for the app is 5.7mb and only going to get larger. Which means that every time the users need to update the app, they have to download the 5.7 meg apk to update. If we roll out more than one release in a week, it can eat through a significant portion of their data plan as well as time as they have to sit and wait for it to download and install.

Is there a better way to do this? Some way to patch the versus completely replacing the application on the host device so that we deploy smaller patches?

I've tried looking for examples of "host" applications, where the actual application is just a shell for a downloadable set of libraries, sort of like a plugin system, but couldn't find any examples.

Are there any resources or a standardised way to accomplish this?

Also worth noting this is a react-native app and we're already running proguard and splitting apks based on architecture to reduce the apk size.

Comment: It depends upon your update definationat, what components are updated in release, just release the update component or write logic within app to identify and download updated components. e.g. we use SQLite database to store user required data and instead of uploading complete apk for database update. We just point to server to check if latest SQL version is available then just update database.

Comment: @Amod Gokhale So for instance we may have a specific UI component, , like, our form component which would need to be updated to resolve a bug, rather than update the entire APK, what you're saying is we would separate those components into for instance individual libs, and then implement something in the root application which checks the version of that against an authority (i.e. a remote server) and downloads the lib into the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have chance to examine [CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/)? It basically allows you to push updates only for javascript part (the bundle) of your app, on-the-fly, without making your users download a new version of the apk.

If you add new native code to your project, you will still need to build and release a new apk though.

How it works is that, when you update the javascript code in your app,  you push a new release. When users run the application, CodePush checks if there is a new version available and if there is, update it immediately and restart the app if you mark the mentioned release as `mandatory` or use the newly downloaded bundle version on next run.

Edit: react-native library of CodePush is [here on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push).

Comment: As an example one production app I've worked on clocks in at 20MB for the APK, and a CodePush update uses only 500KB.

Comment: Is there a server-side component to this, I see the SDK and CLI tool but no server-side component on github? The organization this is for is pretty heavily against using services we can't deploy and manage ourselves on our infrastructure (we can't deploy critical services within the US or on US owned servers). Also, does this only apply to the bundled JS? What if we have some native logic that needs updating, for instance we have a class that deals with some calculations implemented in Java that might need updating. CodePush, it looks really well thought out, but seems to only deal with assets

Comment: @JeffU. CodePush is a free service offered by Microsoft and there is no self-hosted version of it. And it handles with react-native javascript bundle updates. If you need to update native-code (java in your case), as i said, you'll need to release an apk update.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it's got me on the right track, I've got confirmation we can use CodePush to start to get at least the react-native portion of the application and any assets updating, with a longer-term goal of getting off of Microsofts hosted service (before they start charging for it) and implementing something similar ourselves that handles binary diffs of the APK for self-updating of the whole APK in addition to the assets, as well as a server-side portion within our core app to handle the version checking and diffs. Thanks for the help!